# how do i get mongodb metrics request/sec

Tags: mongodb

How do I get mongo db metrics for request/sec or trasactions/sec something similar?

the closes I could find was this `db.serverStatus().network.numRequests` but this is the total number of requests.

Comment: See [Mongodb Monitoring](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/monitoring/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

For, e.g. requests/sec:

Read the # of requests metric every second in your monitoring application, subtract previous value from current value => # of requests made in the last second.